# call route in laravel blade if exists only

Tags: laravel, routes, laravel-blade

I have an ajax function which will use an URL.

```
ajaxMyFunction('{{route('myroute.route1')}}', function (result) { //do stuff });
```

I want to call the route **only if it exists** in my **dynamic** route list because Laravel throws exception if `myroute.route1` doesn't exist yet.

Is there a way to check route before render it inside blade, like when we check views ?

```
@if(View::exists('myroute.route1'))
```

I tried, `Route::has('myroute.route1')` but it doesn't work as well.

Thanx for your help guys ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As I explained in my Laravel best practices repo, you [shouldn't mix JS and Blade syntax](https://github.com/alexeymezenin/laravel-best-practices#do-not-put-js-and-css-in-blade-templates-and-do-not-put-any-html-in-php-classes). To make it work, do something like this on the backend:

```
let route = {{ Route::has('myroute.route1') ? route('myroute.route1') : 'false' }}
```

And then in JS, you will be able to do something like this:

```
if (route) {
    ajaxMyFunction(route, ....);
}
```

Comment: thanx for the trick [very helpful] , but in my current context I really need to put it inside blade :)